# Openbox isn't loading correctly

Tags: debian, window-manager, desktop, openbox, crunchbang

I'm on Crunchbang 11, 64 bit, it is a Debian Wheezy distro.

This morning Openbox isn't loading correctly

[image: link to screenshot]

- All the programs  and shortcuts are working correctly. Conky is
  loading correctly.
- The desktop wallpaper isn't loading
- The menu on top isn't loading, so if I minimize a program, I will not
  be able to know where it is.

here's [autostart](http://pastebin.com/ynKgRpM1), Openbox version 3.5.0-7, display manager is `slim`. Here's [slim.log](http://pastebin.com/S4cpWx7x)

Comment: I tried relogging, i tried restarting crunchbang, the problem persists

Comment: Please add your `~/.config/openbox/autostart*` and the `~/.config/openbox/enviroment` to the question. Also which display manager do you use and which version of Openbox?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens here's autostart http://pastebin.com/ynKgRpM1 openbox version 3.5.0-7 i couldn't find the file called `environment`... display manager is `slim`

Comment: @Fischer Ahh SLiM good. Now if you could get the `/var/log/slim.log` then we should have all we need.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens I included slim.log in my question, and I'll do what you said  in your answer, and reply, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `~/.config/openbox/autostart` there are the following lines.

```
## Group start:
## 1. nitrogen - restores wallpaper
## 2. compositor - start
## 3. sleep - give compositor time to start
## 4. tint2 panel
(\
nitrogen --restore && \
cb-compositor --start && \
sleep 2s && \
tint2 \
) &
```

This part is most likely the cause for your problems.

`nitrogen` is responsible for your background,
`cb-compositor` starts the Compton compositor and
`tint2` is your task bar.

The script above first executes `nitrogen` to restore the previous background.
If this command fails then it will not execute the rest of the script, this behavior is caused by the `&&`.

Since you said your background isn't set the error is probably caused by `nitrogen`.

You could test this by removing `nitrogen` from the `autostart` file.

Like this

```
(\
#nitrogen --restore &&
cb-compositor --start && \
sleep 2s && \
tint2 \
) &
```

Then you need to login again.

If you want the background back then you will need to find out what is wrong with `nitrogen`. My wild guess would be that it can't find the background picture or something like that.

Comment: It worked, I think i should open another question "how to fix nitrogen" rather than trying to fix everything in one question, right? I lost the wallpaper as you said, i could use xfce or other window manager if it's impossible to fix

Comment: @Fischer Yeah, try to figure out what happens when you run `nitrogen --restore` in the console and search the web. If you can't figure out what is going on post a new question. If you find out what was wrong you could add a comment to this question, for the case someone has the same problem.

Comment: `nitrogen --restore` outputs `zsh: command not found: nitrogen`

Comment: i don't know why nitrogen was uninstalled!! i installed it and everything worked